# Connecting curve and plane

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

I want to connect a curve with a plane as shown in the image.
Actually I'm making a fancy chessboard and i want to make it's base.
I've tried bridging edge loops and selecting respective vertices & adding  face (it works but not proper shading as shown in images).

So can anyone please suggest some another method?

[image: edit mode]
[image: object mode]
[image: wireframe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, You want this :

[image: final result]

I would do the following :

Start from your "curved planes gird" :
[image]

Make sure every "curved plane" is merged with his neighbors by selecting everything with <kbd>A</kbd> → open the "Specials" menu with <kbd>W</kbd> and clicking "Remove Doubles".
[image]

Then, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on an border edge of the "gird" in order to select the whole contour :
[image]

Extrude down this edge loop by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> to constraint the extrusion on the Z axis. Click to confirm the action.

Make the extruded loop perfectly plane via a "zero scale" on z-axis: <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and click to confirm.

Then fill the bottom face, either via <kbd>F</kbd>, or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> → Gird Fill which may allow you to make a correct topology.

[image]

In addition, I would make a shade smooth, then turn on the "Auto Smooth" in the Object Data area :
[image]

This will make the whole object look smooth while keeping the sharp edges like they're supposed to look like.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot. By the way did you made this video or it's available on the internet somewhere? Just curious....

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo read [What is the process for creating gifs for questions and answers?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers)

Comment: I made them myself, there are plenty softwares to do that. I usually use ShareX or Screen to Gif.

Answer (score 1):

1.Add a NURBS surface and use Alt C > to mesh in object mode;
2. Extrude vertices, join them with edges and make faces;
3. Use Array to make the board.